# How to make a custom Eclipse build?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I've run in trouble building and packaging our Eclipse-based application. Here is an 'Our Application' consists of 4 Eclipse plug-ins. It's RCP based now (but it's easy to migrate to IDE platform, AFAIK?). It's building and packaging fine, with a simple .product build descriptor.

But now I've faced a problem, as there is a requirement to run that application, with the other plug-ins 'under the same roof'. The plugins are: Papyrus UML, BPMN Designer and (possibly) and XML editor from WTP.

The question is - is it better to 'integrate' this plug-ins in RCP, or to use our plug-ins in an Eclipse IDE? And more specifically - how to create Eclipse IDE build with that and only that plug-ins (features), without JDT and other need-less stuff? What approach should we use, to create such a packaging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using plug-ins in an Eclipse IDE may take you lots of time filtering the unused menu items or something else.
If you want to disable the entire unused plugin, the extension point "org.eclipse.ui.activities" may help you. http://www.vogella.de/blog/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/

Comment: I tried using activities to disable a 'Validate' menu item in my plugins. Using plugin spy shows that menu is provided by o.e.wst.validation.internal.ui.ValidationMenuAction, but using acitivies to disable this menu was not successful. Any ideas how to make this work?